# Magento2 how to get current address data in custom shipping method

Tags: magento2, shipping-methods

How i can get current shipping address details in custom shipping module,

here my code

```
   <?php
public function collectRates(RateRequest $request)
{
    if (!$this->getConfigFlag('active')) {
        return false;
    }

    /** @var \Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\Result $result */
    $result = $this->_rateResultFactory->create();

    //$shippingPrice = $this->getConfigData('price');
    $shippingPrice = "121";
    $method = $this->_rateMethodFactory->create();
    $method->setCarrier($this->_code);
    $method->setCarrierTitle($this->getConfigData('title'));
    $method->setMethod($this->_code);
    $method->setMethodTitle($this->getConfigData('name'));
    $method->setPrice($shippingPrice);
    $method->setCost($shippingPrice);
    $result->append($method);

    return $result;
}
```

?>

i want get the current shipping address and need to display shipping price  based in shipping address.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[If you open this class](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.1/app/code/Magento/Quote/Model/Quote/Address/RateRequest.php) you can able to see some getter/setter for address.

So inside shipping method you have **RateRequest $request** object. You can access this by following way:

```
$request->getDestCountryId();
$request->getDestStreet();
```

etc.

Comment: @sonal, i have little issue with multiple prices. how can i display different price with same shipping methods with variants. i want return multiple variations in above method

Comment: Check usps module, how they handle multiple price variant. https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.1/app/code/Magento/Usps/Model/Carrier.php#L593

Comment: @SohelRana I've created one plugin and called method afterCollectRates. I'm getting RateRequest object empty in the plugin method. Can you please advice?

Comment: @Deeps show your class.

Comment: @SohelRanaI'm able to get the info using CheckoutSession i.e. $this->_checkoutSession->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->getStreet().
But it's not working for visitor's, do you have any idea?

Comment: @Deeps Why you tried this way?Open a question with your class. I will fix that.

Comment: @SohelRana RateRequest is not working in plugin. So now, I tried with overriding the Freeshipping Block and used RateRequest in that. So it's working there now. But, when I have multiple shipping addresses and I try to select another shipping address on checkout page then RateRequest object takes first address in the list and the one selected on checkout page. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

To get the current user selected shipping address in shipping method use
RateRequest Object request in collectRates method as,

```
Country Id          -> $request->getDestCountryId()
Region Id           -> $request->getDestRegionId()
Region code(String) -> $request->getDestRegionCode()
Zipcode (Postal)    -> $request->getDestPostcode()
City                -> $request->getDestCity()
Street              -> $request->getDestStreet()
All quote items     -> $request->getAllItems()
```

Answer (score -2):

Try $request->getDestCity()
To get the shipping destination city