# How to print / echo / debug RateRequest properties in custom shipping method

Tags: checkout, shipping-methods, shipping-address, debugging, debug

I'm able to use this [city dropdown plugin](https://github.com/EaDesgin/Magento2-City-Dropdown) successfully.

Now I'm trying to call shipping vendor API  in my custom shipping module.

Can anyone help me how I can **print / echo / debug** the destination in `Vendor\Module\Model\Carrier\CustomCarrier` -> `collectRates(RateRequest $request)` method / any JS class when user select their region / city ?

I've tried showing the `RateRequest` properties following [this answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/193644) with :

- `echo $request->getDestRegionCode();` or `$request->getDestCity();`
- [debugging to browser console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4323411/how-can-i-write-to-the-console-in-php)
- [Logging the variable to debug.log / system](https://magecomp.com/blog/print-log-in-magento-2/)
- `$this->debugData($request->getDestRegionCode());`

but still not visible , and the application mode has been set to developer as well previously.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Edit : I'm trying to get the destination value when the user select region / city. So the shipping price will change dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom log file to debugging. this is a alternative method.

```
$writer = new \Zend_Log_Writer_Stream(BP . '/var/log/my_debug.log');
$logger = new \Zend_Log();
$logger->addWriter($writer);
$logger->info('This Is Simple Text Log'); //To print simple text log
$logger->info(print_r($myarray, true)); //To print array log
```

Write data into custom log file and check it via manual or CLI like

```
tail -f var/log/my_debug.log
```

After debugging, delete the custom log file.

Comment: Hi thank you for answering. The code is only working when the page is loaded, so only the simple text log is visible. How do I make it work when I select the State / City ?

Comment: You can add this code in PHTML files and PHP file like block, controller etc.

Comment: Also, you can use Ajax Request on the selection of city drop-down to trigger what the destination value you have selected. Or use the submit $request object in Logs to change the shipping price where the object property can be changed.